# Serve both static files from my project (i.e. scripts) and images that users upload

Tags: spark-java

I'm quite new to Spark and trying to figure out how do I achieve the following behavior.

I have in my system two types of files that I want to access:

1. JS/CSS scripts (static), their location is the root directory of my webapp.
2. Images that are not part of my source code. They are uploaded by users to another directory on the server, their location is `/tmp/photos`.

As far as I understand from the documentation with `externalStaticFileLocation()` or `staticFileLocation()` I can only set one of these locations to be accessed. How can I serve these two locations together?

Thanks.

Comment: I think you have to choose between staticFileLocation and externalStaticFileLocation. It's probably not allowed to use them both.

Comment: That makes sense. But still - it's a pretty basic goal to be able to serve both users photos (that are not part of the project/deployment) and all the JS/CSS and other static scripts your HTML pages need.
So how can I do that?

Comment: I think if you use externalStaticFileLocation you are able to serve static files on the go, I mean, without restarting the server. You jist have to implement an endpoint to put those files in that directory.

Comment: @Laercio - thanks for replying but I'm sorry, I don't understand your answer. Of course I'm not going to restart the server. Still I don't understand how can I serve these two locations - one is a directory which is part of the deployment, second is a directory which is just part of the server filesystem.

Comment: Why not let the users upload the images to a DB? That should easily solve 2.

Comment: @Andy - Can you elaborate how can I do that? Or reference some source that explains what you mean? Thanks.